# Printing generated image from teams tab?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a microsoft Teams tab application. I would like to **print an svg image** from this tab (generated on the client)
Normally, this is done by opening a new window and constructing a document to print there (I want to print a generated svg picture)
But in teams client, this option is disabled as opening popups is prohibited by the client.

I have tried some workarounds to open popups mentioned here to no avail:

- using `microsoftTeams.tasks.startTask` to open a popup and try printing from there (does not load because the file is not located on the server at all, it is generated on the client). Maybe this can be still done somehow?
- `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate` to open a new window. Downloads the content instead of opening it.

Comment: why not just launch it in a new browser window, like as a regular <a ...> tag?

Comment: Because it's prohibited by teams to open new windows (blocked for iframe where the tab app runs). I.e. window.open will throw exception if executed in teams clinet

Comment: -popups- are blocked, but it's fine to have a regular <a tag, that works totally fine

Comment: But I need to put a generated (by javascript) image in the new window (and open the print dialog for it, i.e. inject javascript in that window). Can I achieve this with <a> tag? The image is generated on the client itself

Comment: The <a> tag can launch whatever page you want, and you can do whatever you want in that page - generate your image, open the print dialog, you can even close the window using Javascript afterwards

Comment: But how can new window access data that is required to generate and print the image? It sounds like creating a separate application outside of teams. I mean that data needed to generate the image is staying in the old (teams) window. Also the authentication will be lost to get that data? I mean this sounds like "fire and forget" scenario. I was assuming that I use teams app data to generate and print the image.

Answer (score 0):

We have methods to enable print for the entire tab. You can use the following- `microsoftTeams.enablePrintCapability()` and `microsoftTeams.print()`.

Comment: I don't want to print the tab, I want to print an **image generated by the tab**.. I am not sure how could this help me to achive that (please read the discussion above)?

Comment: Currently we can only print entire tab.

Comment: I mean, usually you don't want to print Microsoft Word UI for example, you want to print a document opened in the app. Would be great to have some support for this scenario

Comment: You can suggest this feature in [Microsoft Uservoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).